# mysql Query Columns to Rows

Tags: mysql

```
unitid | row1    | row2   | row3   | row4    | row5    | row6 
-----------------------------------------------------------------
200    | sample1 |sample2 | sample3| sample4 | sample5 | sample6
```

expected OUTPUT

```
200    
sample1
sample2
sample3
sample4
sample5
sample6
```

Comment: It would help in future if you posted the structure of your table, along with the content, any queries you have already tried to show that you have done some research before asking the question, and a bit of formatting doesn't hurt :)

Comment: This is oftentimes referred to as "unpivot." There will be many articles under that heading.

Answer (score 1):

The only easy way to do this is with UNION ALL queries, but with more than one row in your database you may not get the answer you are expecting.

```
SELECT unitid FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT row1 FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT row2 FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT row3 FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT row4 FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT row5 FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT row6 FROM your_table
```

If you have two rows, you will get two `unitid` values, then two `row1` values, etc.